# SQL Server 2012 case statements failing

Tags: sql, sql-server-2012

The following code is failing and it has to be a typo somewhere;

```
SELECT     
    ui.ID AS userid, 
    EmpType = CASE 
                 WHEN c.id IN (1, 3) 
                    THEN 'Public Accounting' 
                 WHEN (SELECT COUNT(csc1.id) 
                       FROM companies_sic_codes AS csc1 
                       WHERE csc1.id = c.id 
                         AND csc1.sic_code IN (9100, 9811)) > 0 
                   THEN 'Government' 
                 WHEN (SELECT COUNT(csc2.id) 
                       FROM companies_sic_codes AS csc2 
                       WHERE csc2.id = c.id 
                         AND csc2.sic_code IN (8930, 8931, 8721, 8742, 8748)) > 0 
                   THEN 'Public Accounting' 
                 WHEN (SELECT COUNT(csc3.id) 
                       FROM companies_sic_codes AS csc3 
                       WHERE csc3.id = c.id 
                         AND csc3.sic_code = 8932) > 0 
                   THEN 'Tax Consulting' 
                 WHEN (SELECT COUNT(csc4.id) 
                       FROM companies_sic_codes AS csc4 
                       WHERE csc4.id = c.id 
                         AND csc4.sic_code IN (8100, 8111)) > 0 
                   THEN 'Law Firms' 
                 WHEN (SELECT COUNT(csc5.id) 
                       FROM companies_sic_codes AS csc5  
                       WHERE csc5.id = c.id 
                         AND csc5.sic_code IN (8211, 8220, 8221, 8222)) > 0 
                   THEN 'Academia' 
                 ELSE 'Corporate In-House' 
            END
FROM         
    dbo.Companies AS c 
INNER JOIN
    dbo.Users_Info AS ui ON c.ID = ui.Current_Company_Number
WHERE     
    (ui.ID = 36075)
```

The `users_info` column `current_company_number` for user 36075 is 26910. The `companies_sic_codes` table for company 26910 has three rows and sic_codes of 7361, 7361, and 7363.  I wouldn't think the duplicate sic_code 7361 would cause a problem. in fact; I deleted that row and get the same results.

The result is:

```
userid     EmpType
36075      'Law Firms'
```

I should be `Corporate In-House`

EDIT

If I remove the "when then 'law firms'" I get the correct results.

Comment: Is it possible you got the company number mixed up? Maybe 29610 or something? You're reasoning sounds correct.

Comment: Is `companies_sic_codes.id` the wrong column to join on?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suspect that you have a company id column in `csc` that you should be joining on rather than `id`. I've also rewritten your query in a form that avoids all the subqueries inside the `case` expression.

```
select
    ui.id,
    case min(
        case
            when csc.sic_code in (9100, 9811) then 1
            when csc.sic_code in (8930, 8931, 8721, 8742, 8748) then 2
            when csc.sic_code in (8932) then 3
            when csc.sic_code in (8100, 8111) then 4
            when csc.sic_code in (8211, 8220, 8221, 8222) then 5
            else 6
        end)
        when 1 then 'Government'
        when 2 then 'Public Accounting'
        when 3 then 'Tax Consulting'
        when 4 then 'Law Firms'
        when 5 then 'Academia'
        when 6 then 'Corporate In-House'
    end
from 
    dbo.Users_Info as ui 
    inner join dbo.Companies as c
        on c.id = ui.Current_Company_Number
    inner join companies_sic_codes as csc
        on csc.id = c.id
where
    ui.id = 36075
group by ui.id
```

Comment: You are correct.  I ended up using pretty much what you have above.  Thanks!